# Amplify - Use email domain for verification code email

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-ses

I am currently looking to use in my amplify project an email based on my domain name (**welcolme@domain.com**) for the verification email.
My domain is well verified and I have a lambda custom message allowing me to customize my email.

Can anyone help me step by step so that I can use my email instead of the default aws email (no-reply@verificationemail.com
) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the steps with new aws console:

**Step 1: add from email**

- Go to your cognito console in aws.
- Choose your userpool and click on Messaging tab.
- Choose Email => Edit.
- Enthe your verified SES identity email+domain.

[image]

**Step 2: use custom message trigger**

- Go to your cognito console in aws.
- Choose your userpool and click on User pool properties tab.
- Click on Add lambda trigger.
- Check messaging block and add your custom function.

[image]